# Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'TextElement.Foreground'

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, contentpresenter

I set up a control template for a button in my wpf application  but I'm having trouble animating the ContentPresenter (which is text) Foreground colour in my storyboard.

Below is the xaml to set up the button

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SaveButton" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Border x:Name="buttonBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Control Grid.Column="0" Template="{DynamicResource save_icon}" 
                     Margin="10,0,0,0"
                     />
            <TextBlock x:Name="buttonContent" 

                              Text="Save"                                   

                              Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 

                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"                                  
                              Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="buttonBorder" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                                To="#000" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="buttonBorder" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                    <ColorAnimation
                                To="#fff" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="buttonContent" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextElement.Foreground"/>
                </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                                To="#fff" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="buttonBorder"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                    <ColorAnimation
                                To="#000" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="buttonContent" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextElement.Foreground"/>
                </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>            


    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However on mouse hover I get the following error - Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'TextElement.Foreground'

Why is this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Clearly, you can't animate the `TextElement.Foreground` Attached property on a `ContentPresenter`. If you only use it as text, then just replace it with a `TextBlock` and then it should work.

Comment: So I replaced <ContentPresenter with <TextBlock and still get the same error.

Comment: Just updated my code to show the change from ContentPresenter to Textblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
```

Full example for doubters

```
        <Button Content="Context">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="bord" Background="CadetBlue">
                    <TextBlock Name="tekst" Text="text" Foreground="Black"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="bord" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="tekst" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Why did I have to do it this way though?

Comment: @ocajian that's why this is considered a bad answer, no explanation at all. Also I'm not sure if it works for the `Background`, are you sure it works for the `Background`? BTW, to specify a `DependencyProperty` you need to use the parentheses to wrap it like that. You can also just use this `(TextBlock.Foreground).Color` (suppose the Foreground should be a `SolidColorBrush`).

Comment: Background/Foreground property contains brush like SolidColorBrush/LinearColorBrush, the first one by default. You want to animate property Color of the brush that's why this path has to be included.

Comment: We just have the so-called `LinearGradientBrush`, not `LinearColorBrush`, also this just works for `SolidColorBrush`.If the original `Foreground` is a `LinearGradientBrush`, there will be some error at runtime.

Comment: @ocajian please confirm about the `Background`, I don't think it works. Normally we can't even set the `Background` for a `ContentPresenter` in XAML code.

Comment: I checked it works. Perhaps you did not notice that contentpresenter was replaced by textblock. Not hard to guess that path contains SolidColorBrush then it will not be working for LinearGradientBrush.

Comment: @Maximus `TextBlock` is just the owner of the DependencyProperty `BackgroundProperty`, but it does not mean it can apply the Background on the `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: @Maximus it works because you apply the `Background` animation ***on the Border*** not on the `ContentPresenter`. That's why your answer is very confusing. Now it was edited and looks better. Also if you apply animations on such elements, you don't need to use `(...)` at all, that's for DependencyProperty path.

Comment: ContentPresenter does not contain property like Background etc, it's meant only for displaying parent's content(property Content or ContentSource).